# Prove that $\overline{A}\subset\overline{B}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,\ B$ denote subsets of a space $X$. Prove that if $A\subset B$, then $\overline{A}\subset\overline{B}$.

**My attempt:**

Let $x\in\overline{A}$

$\implies x\in\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in K}U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha$ is a closed set of $X$ and $U_\alpha\supset A$

$\implies x\in U_\alpha\ \forall\alpha\in K$

How do I proceed?

Comment: You should approach this question backwards. Think first what do you want to prove. You want to show that $x$ is an element of every closed subset containing $B$, so take $V$ be a closed subset containing $B$ what can you say about $V$? Does it contain $A$? if so does it contain $x$, why?

Comment: What definition of the closure of a set are you working with?

Comment: @Yanko I meant let $x\in\overline{A}$. Sorry.

Comment: @Thomas try to answer the questions in my comment.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I've used the definition of $\overline{A}$ in the 2nd line of my proof.

Comment: Do you have this property of closure available to use: If $F$ is closed and $A \subseteq F$, then $\overline{A} \subseteq F$.  If so, then just apply this with $F := \overline{B}$.

Comment: Your $K$ appears out of the blue in the second implication?

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ belongs to every closed set containing $A$, then, in particular, $x$ belongs to every closed set containg $B$ (since $A\subset B$) and therefore $x\in\overline B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \subseteq B$.

Then always $B \subseteq \overline{B}$, and $\overline{B}$ is closed. Both are true from the definition of $\overline{B}$.

Now, $\overline{A} = \bigcap \{C: C \text{ is closed and } A \subseteq C\}$, and
as we saw that $\overline{B}$ is closed *and* contains $A$ (as $A \subseteq B \subseteq \overline{B}$) the set $\overline{B}$ is just *one* of the sets we take the intersection of in this definition of $\overline{A}$ and as the intersection of a (non-empty) family is a subset of each set we are intersecting, by definition, we thus have $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in\overline{A}$ then by definition for every $\varepsilon>0$ the ball $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Since $A\subset B$ then  $$\emptyset\neq B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A=B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (A\cap B)=(B(x,\varepsilon)\cap B)\cap A\Rightarrow B(x,\varepsilon)\cap B\neq \emptyset$$
hence $x\in\overline{B}$.

$\textbf{For a general topological space:}$ Let $X$ be a topological space and $A, B\in X$ such that $A\subset B$. If $x\in \overline{A}$ then by definition for each neighborhood $N$ of $x$ we have $N\cap A\neq\emptyset$. We need to show $\overline{A}\subset\overline{B}$. From the argument above since $A\subset B$ then 
$$N\cap A=N\cap (A\cap B)=(N\cap B)\cap A\neq\emptyset$$
implies $N\cap B\neq\emptyset$ for any neighborhood $N$ of $x$. Hence $x\in\overline{B}$.

Comment: The space may not be metric.

Comment: The argument is the same for any topological space. Instead of balls one uses neighborhoods.

Comment: So you may edit your answer according to the last sentence in your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \bar A$.  Then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.  Then $\exists$ a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ with $x_n\to x$.  But $(x_n)$ is also a sequence in $B$ ($x_n\in A\subset B \forall n$).  Thus $x\in \bar B$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

$A \subset B.$

$\overline{A}= A\cup A'$ , where $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A.$

Need to show that $A' \subset B'$.

Let $x \in A'$. Then every open neighbourhood $K_r(x)$ contains points $y \in A,$ and  $y \not = x.$

But $A \subset B$ :

Thus every open neighbourhood $K_r(x)$ , $x \in A'$, contains points $y \in B$, and $y \not = x$, i.e. $x \in B'$.

Hence: $A' \subset B'.$

Finally:

$\overline{A} =A \cup A' \subset B\cup B'= \overline{B}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \overline{A}$, then $x$ is in all closed set containing $A$.

Every closed set containing $B$ contain $A$, so contain $x$. Then $x$ is in all closed set cointaining $B$, therefore $x\in\overline{B}$